# scp to an authorized folder whose parent is forbidden for me, fails

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, scp, setuid

I try to scp to a folder which is not mine. Its rights are set to 777 but the scp tells me Permission Denied.
When setting its parent folder's rights, whis still is not mine, to 777, then the scp succesfully achieve its mission. Why?

Steps to reproduce:

```
me@host1:/tmp$ ls -lah /applis/foo/
drwxr-xr-x 4 you yourgroup 4.0K Jan 25 14:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 you yourgroup 4.0K Oct  9 13:27 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 you yourgroup 4.0K Jan 25 14:19 build

me@host2:/tmp$ scp data.xslx me@host1:/applis/foo/build/
scp: /applis/foo/build/: Permission denied
# What?! I thought it was 777

me@host1:/tmp$ chmod -R 777 /applis/foo/
me@host1:/tmp$ ls -lah
drwxrwxrwx 4 you yourgroup 4.0K Jan 25 14:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 you yourgroup 4.0K Oct  9 13:27 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 you yourgroup 4.0K Jan 25 14:19 build

me@host2:/tmp$ scp data.xslx me@host1:/applis/foo/build/
data.xlsx                  100% 1006KB  20.8MB/s   00:00
```

Not sure if this counts, but the folder is located here on this type of partition:

```
/dev/mapper/rootvg-root / ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

while I do not seem to have the problem on this kind of partition:

```
/dev/mapper/rootvg-home /home ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

Comment: Does the file already exist in the build folder with non 777 permissions?

Comment: Tried both cases, it does not work wether the file exists or not.

Comment: Do you have ACL implemented?